# zsh for loop exclusion

Tags: for-loop, zsh, glob

This is somewhat of a simple question, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to exclude something from a zsh for loop.  For instance, let's say we have this:

```
for $package in /home/user/settings/*
do
  # do stuff
done
```

Let's say that in `/home/user/settings/`, there is a particular directory ("os") that I want to ignore.  Logically, I tried the following variations:

```
for $package in /home/user/settings/^os (works w/ "ls", but not with a foor loop)
for $package in /home/user/settings/*^os
for $package in /home/user/settings/^os*
```

...but none of those seem to work.  Could someone steer my syntax in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me that the extra `$` may be what's causing your grief.

Try this:

```
for package in /home/user/settings/^os; do
    echo "Doing stuff with ${package}..."
done
```

If you want to limit `${package}` to just directories, use `/home/user/settings/^os(/)`.

Also ensure that you have `extendedglob` set (which I think you do since `ls` works for you):

```
> set -o  | grep -i extendedglob
extendedglob          on
```

Comment: Often the simplest errors are the very hardest to spot. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

That for loop works for me if I `set -o EXTENDED_GLOB` (or `setopt EXTENDED_GLOB`).